# Why is Bundler installing the wrong gem version?

Tags: ruby, bundler

I'm trying to install a custom version of the `composite_primary_keys` gem using Bundler that has some changes we need, based off of the `2.2.2` version.  Our version of the gem is `2.2.2.0` and is hosted on our internal gem server (this 4-digit versioning scheme only exists on our internal gem server).  The app requirements are such that we are on jruby-1.6.7 (`RUBY_VERSION` = 1.8.7), RubyGems version (`gem -v`) 1.3.6, and the latest stable version of Bundler, 1.2.3.

Anyway, my Gemfile looks like this:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
source 'http://gems.internal'

gem 'composite_primary_keys', '2.2.2.0'
gem 'hoe',                    '1.8.3'
```

Executing `bundle` outputs this:

```
$ bundle
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from http://gems.internal/...
Installing rake (10.0.3) 
Installing i18n (0.6.1) 
Installing multi_json (1.5.0) 
Installing activesupport (3.2.11) 
Installing builder (3.0.4) 
Installing activemodel (3.2.11) 
Installing arel (3.0.2) 
Installing tzinfo (0.3.35) 
Installing activerecord (3.2.11) 
Installing json_pure (1.7.6) 
Installing rubyforge (2.0.4) 
Installing hoe (1.8.3) 
Installing composite_primary_keys (2.2.2) 
Using bundler (1.2.3) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

As you can see, `composite_primary_keys` 2.2.2 actually gets installed, not 2.2.2.0.  This is the Gemfile.lock that is generated:

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  remote: http://gems.internal/
  specs:
    activemodel (3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activesupport (3.2.11)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    builder (3.0.4)
    composite_primary_keys (2.2.2)
      activerecord (>= 2.2.0)
      hoe (>= 1.8.3)
    hoe (1.8.3)
      rake (>= 0.8.3)
      rubyforge (>= 1.0.2)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    json_pure (1.7.6)
    multi_json (1.5.0)
    rake (10.0.3)
    rubyforge (2.0.4)
      json_pure (>= 1.1.7)
    tzinfo (0.3.35)

PLATFORMS
  java

DEPENDENCIES
  composite_primary_keys (= 2.2.2.0)
  hoe (= 1.8.3)
```

Now, if I uninstall `composite_primary_keys` and install my version by hand:

```
$ gem uninstall composite_primary_keys
Successfully uninstalled composite_primary_keys-2.2.2
$ gem install composite_primary_keys -v 2.2.2.0
Successfully installed composite_primary_keys-2.2.2.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for composite_primary_keys-2.2.2.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for composite_primary_keys-2.2.2.0...
```

And then execute `bundle`:

```
$ bundle        
Using rake (10.0.3) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.5.0) 
Using activesupport (3.2.11) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.11) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.35) 
Using activerecord (3.2.11) 
Using composite_primary_keys (2.2.2.0) 
Using json_pure (1.7.6) 
Using rubyforge (2.0.4) 
Using hoe (1.8.3) 
Using bundler (1.2.3) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

It keeps my custom gem.  Running bundle update at this point updates the `Gemfile.lock`:

```
$ bundle update composite_primary_keys
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/........
Fetching gem metadata from http://gems.internal/...
Using rake (10.0.3) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.5.0) 
Using activesupport (3.2.11) 
Using builder (3.0.4) 
Using activemodel (3.2.11) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.35) 
Using activerecord (3.2.11) 
Using composite_primary_keys (2.2.2.0) 
Using json_pure (1.7.6) 
Using rubyforge (2.0.4) 
Using hoe (1.8.3) 
Using bundler (1.2.3) 
Your bundle is updated! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

The Gemfile.lock now looks like this:

```
GEM
  remote: http://rubygems.org/
  remote: http://gems.internal/
  specs:
    activemodel (3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.11)
      activemodel (= 3.2.11)
      activesupport (= 3.2.11)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activesupport (3.2.11)
      i18n (~> 0.6)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.2)
    builder (3.0.4)
    composite_primary_keys (2.2.2.0)
      activerecord (>= 2.2.0)
    hoe (1.8.3)
      rake (>= 0.8.3)
      rubyforge (>= 1.0.2)
    i18n (0.6.1)
    json_pure (1.7.6)
    multi_json (1.5.0)
    rake (10.0.3)
    rubyforge (2.0.4)
      json_pure (>= 1.1.7)
    tzinfo (0.3.35)

PLATFORMS
  java

DEPENDENCIES
  composite_primary_keys (= 2.2.2.0)
  hoe (= 1.8.3)
```

## My Guess

My suspicion is Bundler somehow relies on how RubyGems implements the <=> operator...

```
require 'rubygems'
Gem::Version.new('2.2.2') <=> Gem::Version.new('2.2.2.0') # => 0
Gem::Version.new('2.2.2') == Gem::Version.new('2.2.2.0') # => true
```

Can anyone confirm?  Is this expected behavior?  Would this be a good argument for avoiding minor version numbers of 0, in case the version number ever loses a digit?  e.g.

```
Gem::Version.new('2') == Gem::Version.new('2.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0') # => true
```

Answer (score 0):

Although this doesn't directly answer your question. I faced a similar problem in the past and ended up making the custom gem an extension of the other gem. i.e. to patch functionality in "my-awesome-gem" you would call it "my-awesome-gem-custom" or something similar. Trust me, the route you're going down is fraught with dependency nightmares. :)

One note though is to pay attention to the differences in the require [Custom Gem Naming](http://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/#consistent-naming) for an extension gem, as they are slightly different. "require /x/y/z" versus "requre x_y_z". Doing it this way should allow you to use Ruby's open classes to layer or override the functionality as needed.